# AJAX button (only one click is required)

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I have an AJAX function as below. The code has some bugs which I do not know how to solve it. What I want to do is, everytime I click on a button (one time only), it will straightaway save the value of that button into the database, but what happened was, it required user to click twice in order to save the value of that button. Is there anyone can help me on this as I'm new in AJAX and jQuery? Thanks!!!

HTML

```
<fieldset>
<input type="radio" id="start2'+i+'" name="oris'+i+'" value="2" onClick="get(id,2);">
<input type="radio" id="start1'+i+'" name="oris'+i+'" value="1" onClick="get(id,1);">
</fieldset>
```

AJAX

```
 function get(startId){
 var objectA = parseInt(startId.substr(4,1));
 var id = parseInt(startId.substr(5,1));
 var idNumber = "<?php echo $_GET['idNumber']; ?>";

 $('#start'+objectA+id).click(function(){

 jQuery.ajax({

 url: 'followingPage.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: {" field1value": + objectA, "idNumber": + idNumber, "id": +id  },
 success: function(results){
 top.location="submission.php?idNumber=<?=$_GET['idNumber'];?>";
 }
 });
 });
 }
```

Comment: Sorry do you want to generate the radio buttons withjs 
Also dont use a onClick wired up your events using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").click( function() {
     var idNumber = "<?php echo $_GET['idNumber']; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'followingPage.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {" field1value": + $(this).val(), "idNumber": + idNumber, "id": + $(this).attr("id")  },
       success: function(results){
         top.location="submission.php?idNumber=<?=$_GET['idNumber'];?>";
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

Something like this ?

Comment: Actually I want it to be clicked once only, then the value will be saved into the database. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood I thought you wanted the user to click twice I've updated the answer so that you only have to click once.

Answer (score 0):

HTML part Add

```
    <form onSubmit="return false;" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks bowbou, I have tried this, but these buttons doesn't work this way. The reason why I'm using fieldset is because it has some effects, whenever user put the cursor on the buttons, it will be highlighted accordingly like 1 up to 5 star. Example of the buttons is as per in this page http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = false;

 $('#start'+objectA+id).click(function(){
 if(flag){ return false; } //prevent multiple click
  flag = true;  
  //do your stuff here   


});
```